# Which Visual Studio Express edition is required for WCF development?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-express

Pls let me know, which Visual Studio **Express edition** can be used to develop WCF web services?

Is it Express 2013 for Windows Desktop or Express 2013 for Windows?

Comment: I imagine all 3 has some access to the WCF libraries are they are rather integral.  I would question how/where you plan to use the web services.  You want "For Windows" if you are wanting Windows 8 / Windows Phone (Metro Apps).  You probably want For Windows Desktop.  Though, if you are heavily web focused you might consider Express for Web.

Comment: @vossad01 my intention is to develop web services (SOAP, REST, XML-RPC) and later consume them in asp.net application.

Comment: In order to create WCF services, you would have to use Visual Studio Express for Web. Atleast in VS 2013 express, It does not have a project type of WCF.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a site for three Visual Studio Express 2013 download versions.

http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx

For WCF and any other web development, you will want to use the first option *Express 2013 for Web*

Comment: WCF is not only for web.  It can be used in Windows services, WinForms, WPF applications, etc.  All you really need is `System.Runtime.Serialization` and `System.ServiceModel`.

Comment: @Tim Can I develop web services (SOAP, REST, XML-RPC) using above mentioned namespaces. Please clarify.

Comment: @GURMAILse - Those two namespaces are used in WCF (`System.ServiceModel` is an essential part of WCF).  WCF is primarily SOAP, but can be used with REST (though depending on what you're trying to do WebAPI may be a better choice there).  The point I was making was that any version of Express should have the necessary components for creating the service.  Hosting it may be more limited depending on the version (Probably Web for IIS, Windows Desktop for console or Windows Service, etc).

Comment: GURMAILse if you are primarily developing for the Web I recommend getting the Web version of Visual Studio.  based on the Web Protocols you are looking to use, I think this is the best fit.  Though @Tim makes a very valid point that WCF can be used outside of pure web development, which makes it a very powerful tool. If you will later be building separate applications it would depend if they are Desktop apps like WPF or Web Apps like and MVC site.  That might also sway your decision.  I think you can have multiple versions of Express but it's not ideal.